# Get HostWeb ClientContext in Remote Event Receiver bound to List Item actions on AppWeb

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, provider-hosted-app

I have an AppWeb Remote event receiver bound to ItemChanged event on list which is in AppWeb scope(defined in sharepoint project declaratively). Whenever an item in this list is changed, i need to access different list, which is present in the HostWeb scope, and make there some changes.

```
ClientContext hostContext = TokenHelper.CreateAppEventClientContext(properties, false)
```

does not work since i am in appWeb context. I cannot even access this way

```
ClientContext hostContext = new ClientContext(properties.AppEventProperties.HostWebFullUrl)
```

since AppEventProperties are null (because RER is bound to ListItemEvents).
Is there any way i could achieve this without having to hardcode the HostWebUrl?
Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this: http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2014/07/remote-event-receivers-on-host-web-ClientContext.html

I think Chris is describing there exactly your issue.

Comment: Although this article did not describe exactly my issue, since it is talking about creating the context of host web, it helped me to find the solution.